# VS Code 1.86 line of code started following me in split at top of screen as I scroll. Why?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just upgraded to VS Code 1.86, and it has started making the top / first / starting part of the code block I am looking at always stay shown at the top of the editor area while I scroll, in a split view/section. How can I get rid of this and make it go back to the old appearance without this feature?

AKA: Why did this change, and how can I disable sticky scroll in the editor area of VS Code?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

VS Code started changing the default value of the `editor.stickyScroll.enabled` setting to `true` in VS Code 1.86 (see [the iteration plan](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/201255) and issue ticket [#202655](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/202655)).

There are multiple ways to turn it back off:

- Right click the sticky scroll panel to be prompted to toggle it off
- OR Run `View: Toggle Sticky Scroll` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)
- OR Open your user [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) by running `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)` in the command palette, and write `"editor.stickyScroll.enabled": false` and then save the change

Sticky Scroll was [released in version 1.70](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70#_editor-sticky-scroll) (July 2022), but up until version 1.86, it had been disabled by default.

The default has now been fully changed to on [in version 1.87](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_87#_editor-sticky-scroll). You can also change the maximum number of lines that the sticky scroll panel takes up with the `editor.stickyScroll.maxLineCount` setting.

Note that sticky scroll is also supported in several other areas of the VS Code workbench, such as the terminal and tree views, which each have their corresponding settings and commands.

If you want to adjust the colour, open settings.json, create a key for `workbench.colorCustomizations`, and then trigger suggestions and type "stickyscroll" and you'll see what options there are.

Comment: Note in the command pallet this has been split off into 4 options.  `View: Toggle Editor Sticky Scroll`, `Terminal: Toggle Sticky Scroll`,  `View: Toggle Notebook Sticky Scroll`,  `View: Toggle Tree Sticky Scroll`. Best search for `Sticky Scroll` and click the option that best reflects the issue.

Comment: Wish I knew this before I spent 3 hours trying to figure out how I should even explain this to google.

Comment: @coderDcoder whenever you notice something changes after an update, you can also just check the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the approach I found quick and easy (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78130822/5783745)):

1. Right click on the sticky scroll header (i.e. the lines that are stuck to the top of your code/file)
2. Click the option to disable sticky scroll

Comment: note: this was basically already stated in my pre-existing answer post. but I didn't know you didn't need to hold ctrl while clicking. I was basing off a comment by a VS Code maintainer who claimed that holding ctrl was necessary. I've since edited my answer.

Answer (score -2):

I was unsuccessful using command palette to attempt to set `"editor.stickyScroll.enabled": false` because of **read-only** permission.

Instead, I clicked on the gear icon at the bottom left of the VS Code window and selected "Settings". Then, searched "editor.stickyScroll" and was able to turn off **Editor > Sticky Scroll: Enabled**
[image]

[image]

Comment: what exactly was read only? your user-level settings.json file? also, you don't "_using command palette to attempt to set "editor.stickyScroll.enabled": false_". you use the command palette to open the user-level settings.json file, where you put that JSON property.

Comment: When I tried your solution VSCode said I had "read-only" permissions. I found a simple work around going to 'Settings' and then unchecking "Shows the nested current scopes during the scroll at the top of the editor". If this helps somebody else, great!