# Visual Studio Code with Rainbow CSV extension keeps the top line of a (specific) file at the top of the editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my Visual Studio Code, I have a raw text file, (.txt), which has its top line stuck to the top of its editor when I scroll down below the top line. This issue persists after restarts and closing and reopening of the file.

**I am using the Rainbow CSV extension**. This is not due to VS Code's builtin sticky scroll feature.

This issue persists after restarts and closing and reopening of the file.

[image: Screenshot of the issue.]

Comment: Does this happen if you disable all extensions? It seems like the sort of behaviour I'd expect from an extension that treats text files as data with the first line being a header.

Comment: @DavidWaterworth This worked, thanks! I'll try checking the settings of all extensions now.

Comment: **for people not using the rainbow CSV extension,** you probably want https://stackoverflow.com/q/77768982/11107541 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem. This can be fixed by disabling the "*Enable_sticky_header*" setting in the "*Rainbow CSV*" extension.

Answer (score 1):

Check, if there is "Sticky Scroll" enabled. View-> Apperance

Comment: This setting is not related to the issue. I have already tried this.

Answer (score 0):

Press right click on these lines sticky and click option disabled sticky, this worked for me.