# How do you disable sticky scroll in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidentally enabled sticky scroll somehow, and now when I scroll the lines of code at the top stay there, which is not desirable.

Comment: You didn't enable it. It was in the recent update.

Comment: @BrendanOtherwhyz oh wow. Thought I'd hit some unlucky key combination and accidentally enabled it - what an awful update!

Answer (score 3):

The solution is:

1. Right click on the sticky scroll header (i.e. the lines that are stuck to the top of your code/file)
2. Click the option to disable sticky scroll

(The obvious solution of setting sticky line count to 0, as desired, doesn't actually work.)

[image]